# Adding a method to an class of an object created by another class

Tags: python, inheritance

I am using python's `calendar` class, which has a method `monthdatescalendar` that returns a list of objects of the type `datetime.date`. Suppose I had a method I wanted to add to this latter class. Should I be inheriting calendar, calling the parent class' monthdatescalendar() function and adding what I need manually in a loop? Is there a better way? Simply declaring `day.foo() = something` below throws an attribute error.

```
class Child(calendar.Calendar)
    [...]
    def monthdatescalendar(year,month):
        list = super().monthdatescalendar(year, month)
        # here, add some method/data to each datetime.date object
        for week in list:
            for day in week:
                # do something
                
        return list
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is the wrong solution to this problem. You need to use composition. We don't extend the functionality of existing classes in Python. But we *can* wrap them.

```
class MyDateWrapper:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def foo(self):
        # Do stuff with self.value here
```

Then, when you call `monthdatescalendar`, just do

```
my_date = [MyDateWrapper(x) for x in my_calendar.monthdatescalendar(year, month)]
```